# What is the $\mathscr{L}$ operator for $u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u^3=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading Strauss' book on Partial Differential Equations. There is the following equation:

$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u^3=0$$

In a section where he talks about the $\mathscr{L}$ operator. What is the $\mathscr{L}$ operator for this differential equation? Is it

$$\mathscr{L} = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+u^2$$

Or the $\mathscr{L}$ operator does not exist because this equation is not linear?

Comment: If "L" stands for linear then most certainly not. You can always define an operator that does that by simply using the dot notation $$O=\partial_t^2 -\partial_x^2+(\cdot)^3$$

Comment: $\mathcal{L}$ usually stands for linear, but there is no reason why we couldn't use it to represent a nonlinear operator such as in your example $$\mathcal{L} := \partial_{tt} - \partial_{xx} + u^{2}$$ Also, $\mathcal{L}$ could possibly refer to the _linearisation_ of a nonlinear operator $\mathcal{N}$. In short, it all depends on the context given. What chapter of Strauss does he talk about the $\mathcal{L}$ operator?

Comment: @mattos This is from the first chapter, page 2. I just started studying PDE's.

Comment: I just checked, it seems Strauss uses $\mathcal{L}$ to define a linear operator only. So an operator $\mathcal{L}$ doesn't exist for the PDE $$u_{tt} - u_{xx} + u^{3} = 0$$ under this definition, as Ninad stated above.